# Values generated by math.random in a while loop

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

Started learning javascript yesterday! My first day in programming. :-)
How can I retrieve the random numbers generated before the condition `!=2` is met? Thanks

```
var count = 0;
function pcNum() { 
    return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));  
}
while (pcNum()!=2) {
    count++;           
}
```

Comment: Save the generated numbers in an array of similar.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks, l've tried but if I append with the methods l've learned so far (i.e xyz.push(pcNum()) it doesn't work since it inserts a series of numbers included the 2... so l think it's a different set from the one which activate and stop the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Javascript! One way of accomplishing this would be to store your random numbers in an array and use your existing `count` variable as the array index. On every pass in the `while` loop, increment the count and push a new random number into the array:

```js
var count = 0;

function pcNum() { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);  
}

// randomNumbers[count] = first random number
var randomNumbers = [pcNum()];

while (randomNumbers[count] != 2) {
    count++;
    randomNumbers.push(pcNum());
}

console.log('ran %s times', count);
console.log(randomNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and clear explanation!  Enjoying my first javascript day :-) If l had known programming was so interesting, l would have not embraced seo and web marketing 20 years ago :-)

Comment: Glad to help out! Yeah, programming is incredibly interesting and fulfilling as a hobby and/or career - I'm sure your experience with SEO and marketing will prove useful. I highly recommend MDN (especially over W3Schools) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
function pcNum() {
    return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
var nums = [];
for (var num = pcNum(); num != 2; num = pcNum()) {
  nums.push(num);
}
var count = nums.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num=null;
 while ((num=pcNum())!=2) {
   count++;           
}
alert(num);
```

This stores the current number in the var *num*. If you want to store all:

```
var num=null,array=[];
while((num=pcNum())!=2) array.push(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var count = 0;
function pcNum() { 
return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));  
                 }

while (pcNum()!==2) {
    pcNum();//Random generator
count++;           }
```

Try Like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what they are, you can use console.log (you'll have to open your browsers debugger to see that).

```
var count = 0;
function pcNum() { 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    console.log(num);
    return(num);  
}
while (pcNum()!==2) {
    count++;           
}
```

If you want access to it, you'll need to store the result.

```
var count = 0;
function pcNum() { 
    return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));  
}
var num = pcNum();
while (num!==2) {
    count++;  
    //do something with num
    num = pcNum();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let myarray=[];
var count = 0;
function pcNum() { 
    return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));  
}
while (num=pcNum())!==2) {
    myarray.push(num);
    count++;           
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this inline with an array and the array.push() method.

```
var count = 0;
var randArray = [];
function pcNum() { 
    return(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}

while (randArray.push(pcNum())!=2) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: `push` returns the length of the array

Comment: You're right; I'm chalking this up to a sleepy morning ha. My bad.